# what is the equivalent code for php in c#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am doing a cross domain post in .net, but in net they have provided me with php example....i would like to convert the php code to .net. Please help.

```
 <?php
        header('Content-type: text/html');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        $uri = 'http'. ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 's' : null) .'://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        echo('<p>This information has come from <a href="' . $uri . '">' . $uri . '</a></p>');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);         
request.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/html");
request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

`$_SERVER` is equivalent to `Request.ServerVariables[]`